# Error while publishing an API in the WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, amazon-ec2

When I publish an API in the WSO2 API Manager, the following error occurs:

```
Gateway Failures
Failed to Publish Environments
Production and Sandbox
Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Authentication failure
```

Comment: Please provide the logs and mentioned the API Manager version you are using.

Answer (score 5):

This could be due to an authentication failure. Please check whether username/password within `<Environments>` content element of root `<APIGateway>` element in api-manager.xml (`<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`) is correct

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue.
When checking the logs I saw this:

```
URL context: /hrs/admihrsd/osb/documentWS/2.0.0 is already registered with the API: novakgo--hrs-admihrsd-osb-document-service:v2.0.0
```

The issue was someone was trying to publish a new API with the same context as another one. They should change the context and publish again, and the error is fixed. Context have to be unique.